# How to display blob with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Why can't my php display the image?

```
<?php
  include("sql.php");
  //$sql = "SELECT * FROM filesdb WHERE fileid = 5";
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM filesdb WHERE fileid =$id";
  echo $sql."<br>";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //header('content-type: image/jpeg');

        echo  "<br>Fileid:".$row['fileid'];
        echo  "<br>FileName:".$row['filename'];
       header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
       echo "<br>".$row['dbforfile'];
     }
```

it can display `fileid` and `filename`, but not `dbfofile`, which is a BLOB.

Comment: Don't output anything before `header()`. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Do you want PHP to render **only** the image, or the image as **part of** a HTML document?

Comment: You can't have HTML elements like `<br>` in an image.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

If you're downloading the file contents, you must not put HTML elements around it.

You can also only send one image at a time, so there's no point in looping.

```
<?php
include("sql.php");
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM filesdb WHERE fileid = 5";
$id = $_GET['id'];
// do some validation here to ensure id is safe
$sql = "SELECT dbforfile FROM filesdb WHERE fileid =$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('content-type: image/jpeg');
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['dbforfile'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing one image, so you don't need a loop.  But if you want to do multiples; you need to use an `img` tag and call another PHP script as if it were an image in the `src` and have that script output the image (with headers).  Or you can use base64 encoded `data` as the image source in the tag:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
     echo "<br>Fileid:".$row['fileid'];
     echo "<br>FileName:".$row['filename'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['dbforfile']).'"/>';
 }
```

Comment: While this works, it's not optimal as that image can't be cached by the browser and must be fetched from the database, encoded, stuffed into the HTML, and decoded each and every time.